# Suggestions/Alternatives to Sahat/Satellizer for Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, jwt, satellizer

I want to use a token-based authentication module for my Ionic 2 application. But as you can see, *Satellizer* is not that suitable for **Angular2**, mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/issues/320).

Also I found [this](https://github.com/ronzeidman/ng2-ui-auth), an *angular2* repository for authentication based on *angular1*'s Satellizer. But I am not sure about using this solution.

---

Any help about this issue or any different suggestions for using different modules (open source or low cost, auth0 is out of my budget) is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you not sure about the solution you found? Have you tested it? Please note that there was a major new version of it released 6 days after you posted this question.

Comment: @mdentinho I decided and used [PassportJs](http://passportjs.org/) for my project. I am not sure about the new version of what; sahat/satellizer, or ronziedman/ng2-ui-auth ?

Comment: The solution you found ([ronziedman/ng2-ui-auth](https://github.com/ronzeidman/ng2-ui-auth/releases)) had a new major version released.

Comment: @mdentinho Thank you for the update, I will consider it for my future projects.